# Does playing games damage the phone

Tags: overheating

I have a galaxy s4 GTI9505 and i'm playing N.O.V.A 3. While playing, my phone gets quite hot. I wonder if playing such games will damage my phone?

Answer (score 3):

Usually your phone will just shut off if it reaches critical temperatures.
But long runs on high temperature are able to damage your phone so components wear off faster. Especially your battery will suffer and will have lower capacity over time.